# How do I get rid of a blue bar at the top of my app when I deploy flutter application as a web app on my phone?

Tags: flutter, mobile-safari, mobile-application

after deploying my flutter application as a web app, I wanted to save it on my IOS device as an app on my homescreen from safari. However, when I go on Safari, there's a blue bar at the top of my screen (I don't see this blue bar on Chrome or Google). I don't think this has anything to do with the code but it makes my UI look bad and I want to get rid of it. Is there anyway to do so? If you do think it has something to do with my code, here's the GitHub for it: https://github.com/MatthewGerges/Conversingo_Flutter_Mobile_App

I tried going on Chrome where the blue bar doesn't exist and saving it on my homescreen but there's no option to do so in the Chrome or Google app on iPhone. I also tried getting rid of the SafeArea widget in my app but that didn't work.
[Picture of the Blue Bar in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dG7E.png)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think it is defined either by the `background_color` or `theme_color` in the `manifest.json` file. It should be located in the web folder of your flutter project